# Can I create tree with single view object in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

Tags: oracle11g, jdeveloper

I have a table Menu_tab it consist columns menu_id,menu_desc,Parent_id where every node taking its parent id node from parent_id column. Now I want to create a tree with this single table using jdeveloper. Help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can there is a sample of this on the ADF Code Corner
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/32-tree-table-from-single-vo-169174.pdf